# Finding and grouping same values, (float vectors) in nested lists

Tags: python, sorting, vector, grouping

I have a list containing vectors (float x, y ,z values) and i'm trying group the same values together....

Here is a working example on a single list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

example_list = [1,5,1,4,2,5,5,4,5,7,2,1,7,9] 

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in example_list:
     d[item].append(item)

groupedlist = sorted(d[x] for x in d)

# Returns [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5], [7, 7], [9]]
```

I'm trying the achieve the same result for nested lists of 3D Vectors (X,Y,Z)...

```
example_vectorlist = [[1,2,4], [1,2,3], [3,4,3], [1,3,2], [5,6,7], [3,4,3], [5,6,7]]

# Desired output = [[1,2,4],[[1,2,3],[1,2,3]],[1,3,2],[[3,4,3], [3,4,3]],[[5,6,7], [5,6,7]]
```

Comment: Why you have 2 `[5,6,7]` in your desire output?

Comment: Your "Desired output" isn't a grouping of your original list of vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the keys for your `defaultdict` into tuples:

```
from collections import defaultdict

example_list = [[1,2,4], [1,2,3], [3,4,3], [1,3,2], [5,7,1], [3,4,3], [5,6,1]]

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in example_list:
    d[tuple(item)].append(item)

groupedlist = sorted(d[x] for x in d)
```

The problem with just using the original "vectors" as keys to `d` is that lists aren't hashable; making tuples of them addresses this.

Answer (score 1):

Without using `defaultdict`:

```
example_vectorlist = [[1,2,4], [1,2,3], [3,4,3], [1,3,2], [5,7,1],[3,4,3], [5,6,1]]
d = {}
for el in example_vectorlist:
    try:
        d[tuple(el)].append(el)
    except KeyError:
        d[tuple(el)] = [el]
print d.values()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output does not reflect what you have as input, if you want to group common sublists you can use `itertools.groupby`, considering you want sorted output using a dict and then sorting makes less sense than just creating the  groupings from the sorted list using groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby

print([list(v) for _,v in groupby(sorted(example_vectorlist))])
```

Which for you original list outputs the same:

```
example_list = [1,5,1,4,2,5,5,4,5,7,2,1,7,9]
print([list(v) for _,v in groupby(sorted(example_list))])
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2], [4, 4], [5, 5, 5, 5], [7, 7], [9]]
```